# Error: Bad value for attribute href on element a: Illegal character in query: not a URL code point

Tags: html, w3c-validation

I just started learning to make websites and still on my way learning, this is my first website and I used the w3c validator and got this error I don't know what it means. Please help!

> Error: Bad value for attribute href on element a: Illegal character in query: not a URL code point.
>   From line 150, column 6; to line 150, column 272
>   
> ↩                   < a target="_blank" href="http://rover.ebay.com/rover/1/705-53470-19255-0/1?icep_ff3=2 & pub=5575…p_item=201424810519&ipn=psmain&icep_vectorid=229515&kwid=902099&mtid=824&kw=lg">

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow; please consider editing your question in order to provide us with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Since you haven't showed us the code causing the error, it's impossible for us to know what in particular is causing the issue.

Comment: 1. Check your URL. 2. a URL in an attribute must be encoded, in particular `&` should be written as `&amp;`. If that doesn't solve the issue, please provide the exact contents of line 150 of your HTML.

Comment: Hi guys the website is kingoflarp.com.au. sorry i thought i copied the link in the question; a target="_blank" href="http://rover.ebay.com/rover/1/705-53470-19255-0/1?icep_ff3=2 & pub=5575…p_item=201424810519&ipn=psmain&icep_vectorid=229515&kwid=902099&mtid=824&kw=lg" thanks in advanced. Just to add this link was copied off ebay partner network affiliate link do i still need to use the &amp; for &

Comment: That's not the link. You see the `...` between `pub=5575` and `p_item=`? That  `...` indicates that there's quite a lot more link between the beginning and the end.